# Is HTTPS over LAN effective?

Tags: encryption, tls, man-in-the-middle, tunneling

From my understanding, while HTTPS does not stop a mitm, it makes it so the mitm cannot read the plaintext requests. But, the mitm could still tamper with the public/private keys anyways, so in came the use of encryption certificate companies. However, as far as I know these are meant for use over the internet. So over LAN, couldn't a mitm still do key tampering and view the plain data? If so, is there a way to effectively deploy HTTPS on LAN?

Comment: Forget security for a moment. Is there a way to deploy HTTPS on LAN *at all*? Do you know one? How does it work? I assume you have found one, or you wouldn't be asking whether it's secure.

Comment: @user253751 yes, of course there is ... If you have a question about that, please post a new question, or just search here for the highly rated questions that talk about it.

Comment: @schroeder *I* know about HTTPS on LANs. I want to know what the *asker* knows about HTTPS on LANs, because that is relevant to how the question should be answered.

Comment: @user253751 Then your clarifying question is very, very oddly phrased ...

Comment: Your entire premise is completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> Is HTTPS over LAN effective?

Sure, it's used all the time. Less commonly within a private home's LAN, but certainly within companies, governments, data centers, warships... Heck, I've even seen it used to secure communication between the various computers on a satellite.

> However, as far as I know these [TLS certificates] are meant for use over the internet.

What gives you that idea? I mean, they're intended for use over a communication system, but there's nothing about them that's inherent to the Internet, or even to IP-based communication at all. You could use them to authenticate and enable key exchange over literally any digital communication where there's some form of address (something to put in Subject field of the certificate) for the remote system that you're connecting to (the web server, in the case of HTTPS).

It doesn't even need to be between computers; you could (if you wanted to for some reason) use them to secure something like local (Unix) domain sockets or named pipes. The same kind of X.509 certificates used for TLS (including HTTPS) are also used for things like secure email (S/MIME) using the destination email address as the subject address.

Sure, the [D]TLS libraries that certificates are usually used with (and that are used to implement HTTPS) are generally built on the assumption that the protocol is either TCP or (for DTLS) UDP, both of which are used over IP which is usually over Ethernet. But that's just because IP, and to a lesser extent TCP and UDP, have pretty conclusively won the protocol wars from the days of IPX, AppleTalk, etc.

> So over LAN, couldn't a mitm still do key tampering and view the plain data?

How would that work? Assuming that the MitM doesn't have the server's private keys (because that's the fundamental assumption of private keys), you can't interfere with the TLS handshake (including the key exchange). The only option would be to impersonate the server, but the legitimate certificate contains the server's public key (so you can't use it yourself unless you have the private key) and a faked certificate shouldn't be trusted.

So the whole thing comes down to "how do you tell a legit cert from a fraud?", which is of course one of the key questions of TLS in general.

> is there a way to effectively deploy HTTPS on LAN?

There are lots of options:

1. Get certificates (from a normal certificate authority, like Verisign or Let's Encrypt or DigiCert or whoever) for all the machines on your LAN - "bob.internal.mycompany.com" is a perfectly valid domain name and can be used a subject name for Bob's machine on your company's LAN - and use those. (The machines don't even need to be reachable over the Internet, they just need to be named in DNS... which you can do over a LAN just fine, it's just UDP and indeed your default DNS server is probably *on* your LAN already; it's usually your router.)
2. Use an internal certificate authority that issues certs just the same as Verisign, etc. and install and trust its cert as a trusted root CA on all your machines. (This approach is extremely common, both for corporate networks and for things like server clusters running in a data center or cloud provider or whatever.)
3. Create self-signed certificates and exchange them beforehand through some secure method (such as physically transferring them on a flashdrive), then install and trust those certificates on the client.
4. Create self-signed certificates and transfer them (as in #3) but just include them (or at least their public key info) with your client app and manually verify that the expected cert / key is presented by the server (an extreme form of cert / public key pinning, but perfectly viable and commonly used for, say, testing mobile apps on a developer's LAN).
5. Use something other than certificate-based authentication. TLS is usually used with certificates, and I've never heard of HTTPS in particular being used without them, but there are several ways to authenticate in TLS. For example, you can use a "Pre-Shared Key" (TLS-PSK) - basically a password - that the server and client know but a MitM doesn't. This is one of the use cases for the Secure Remote Password protocol.

Comment: @KamilKurzynowski pointing out issues with the question in an answer's comment thread is not useful. If you have constructive points to give the author, comment to them.

Answer (score 0):

Https is always over LAN. If you browse a page on the internet you are doing so over LAN as the so called "last mile" is your local network. There is no difference from the security point of view. All the traffic in LAN can be captured by the mitm no matter the origin of it. WAN can also be intercepted so this question does not make any sense.

As for use of the HTTPS in local networks, I would advise reading on the topic of public key cryptography. HTTPS is used on local networks, some use their own CA for managing the internal certificates.

Keys used for the encryption are most likely to be exchanged in a secure way, making their interception (in plain text form) nearly impossible.

By definition, MITM is someone on the network able to intercept the traffic. This threat model assumes that the person can only see network traffic and has no access to participating stations. In this case even self-signed certificate utilizing RSA for key exchange will provide sufficient security.